# Is it possible to get rid of external message in email via powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

---

"This is an external email. Do you know who has sent it? Can you be sure that any links and attachments contained within it are safe? If in any doubt, use the Phishing Reporter Button in your Outlook client or forward the email to ~ I've Been Phished"

---

Above is the external message which is coming in email,the moment when i send email via powershell

Comment: Sounds to me like a self-created transport rule in your exchange server environment.
Do you use Exchange online and send emails from a server by Powershell to EXO mailboxes?

Comment: no, it is failing to send email to EXO mailboxes (Group mailbox/ Specific email DL). How to overcome these problems? @CdkK kindly suggest

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t quite understand what happens when. So, you send mail by powershell. Which command are you using? And where is this message showing up?

Comment: I had given text which starting from  "This is an external email". this 2 line paragraph appearing in start body of email. I'm sending in normal way only in pshell.
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)

Comment: At the recipients outlook?

Comment: yes, exactly :-)

Comment: The only way I know when this happens is when you set a mail flow rule on your Exchange server / EXO that appends a disclaimer at the beginning of every email that you receive. Please check for any rules in your Exchange configuration for that. If so, you can delete the rule or you can define execeptions for either a domain or a sender in that rule to exclude the server where you send mails by Powershell from.

Comment: Got you, Many thanks for the valuable suggestion. Will follow this

Comment: Sure, please let me know if this was the case or if you can't find a rule and the problem will persist

Comment: my admins are not happy to get rid of the transport rule in. Any way that i can manipulate in html?

Comment: You can’t do anything while sending the message because at that moment, the message isn’t attached yet. The message get attached before it leaves the Exchange service towards the mailbox. Instead of disabling the rule at all your admins could make exceptions in the rule to exclude certain sender addresses or even entire domains. On that way they could exclude the sender address from which you send mails by PowerShell.